# useState does not changing after setstate callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch, react-state

I just want to add error message in error state. But when error occurs setError does not changing means does not adding error message. Back-end giving the error message as json format { "error": "error message" } and if I console log that error that works fine but error state is not updating.

```
import { useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useHttpClient = () => {
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState();

    const activeHttpRequests = useRef([]);

    const sendRequest = useCallback(async (url, method = 'GET', body = null, headers = {}) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const httpAbortCtrl = new AbortController();
        activeHttpRequests.current.push(httpAbortCtrl);
         try {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method,
                body,
                headers,
                signal: httpAbortCtrl.signal
            });
            const responseData = await response.json();
            activeHttpRequests.current = activeHttpRequests.current.filter(
                reqCtrl => reqCtrl !== httpAbortCtrl
            );

            if(!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(responseData.error);
            }

            setIsLoading(false);
            return responseData;
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e.message);
            setIsLoading(false);
            throw e;
        }
    }, []);

     const clearError = () => {
         setError(null);
     };

    useEffect(() => {
        //this runs as cleanup function before next time useEffect run or also when an component use useEffect unmount
        return () => {
            activeHttpRequests.current.forEach(aboutCtr => aboutCtr.abort());
        }
    }, []);

     return { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError };
}
```

Comment: Minor question, why do you 2 `componentDidMount`? You can merge both and return the cleanup function from first itself

Comment: Have you try to breakpoint at catch statement and see if it throws error. What http error code your API is sending? 404? 500?

Comment: What's catching the error once you rethrow from the `catch`? You're probably killing the thread.

Comment: It seems to be updating for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-nash-thied?file=/src/App.js. Could you share the part where you see that the state isn't updating?

Comment: How are you validating/verifying that the "error" state isn't being updated? Can you update your question to include an example component using this custom hook that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat it giving 400 code error as i wrote in backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your backend is responding with JSON, that would mean the response status code is probably 200 (successful). Which makes "response.ok" true.

You will have to look at the returned JSON string for valid data or error message.